# Creating a relationship between Salesforce object "Lead" and "Opportunity" in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, salesforce

I am preparing a report on Leads that I am extracting from Salesforce, using PowerBI. I have the Salesforce Objects, and am trying to create a relationship between the Lead and Opportunity objects.

Issue is I can't find a single unique value that connects the two. I thought it would be something like "Lead ID" that would relate to both fields but no such luck. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box on [Lead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) you should see `ConvertedOpportunityId`. It'll be populated only sometimes, depending if your organisation uses lead conversion. There may be more links (maybe custom lookup between the two, maybe something indirect like Lead -> Conversion to Account and Oppty appearing later. Or maybe something with Campaigns and Campaign Members which can be contacts or leads)

Hard to say without knowing more about your business. Go back to the person that asked for report and ask for more details.

You can try bruteforcing it by looking at "describe" information, using Schema Builder in SF setup or looking at [pretty diagrams](https://architect.salesforce.com/diagrams/template-gallery/sales-cloud-overview-data-model) but the result might not be what your client expects.

[image: 4 most likely standard paths from Lead to Opportunity]

Comment: Thank you, that is a very interesting schema! As you correctly guessed, the ConvertedOpoortunityId is indeed blank. I'm trying to find other connections now.

Perhaps this is a question for another topic, but is there a way for PowerBi to detect relationships between two columns automatically?

Comment: I'm not a PowerBI guy, sorry. You could ask your Salesforce Admin to show you schema builder, drag & drop few tables, see what connections form. There's also "schemaspy" plugin for Salesforce, generates bit ugly diagrams but it's great for data migrations, integrations...

Comment: Can you run some kind of full text search in PowerBI? All SF primary keys of one table will always start with same prefix. All Accounts start with 001, Opportunities with 006, Leads with 00Q... If you have some kind of full dump of SF database synchronised you could try searching for 1 lead or opportunity Id and see where else it shows up? http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html

Comment: I wish I had that! I'll have to play around and see where I end up, I think it might also be that something like emails might have to be used for cross referencing but not sure at the moment.